# Gmail on Lumia 820 (new labels)

Tags: gmail, nokia-lumia-820

I added my Google Acount to my Lumia 820. But when I'm sending a message, the new folder (label) Sent Items is created and all messages which are sent from phone are saved here (it is same for deleted items, label Deleted Items is created). How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is your phone running the GDR2/Amber update?